# Django REST Framework serializer field required=false

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

from the documentation:

> read_only
>   Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when serializing a representation, but is not used when updating an instance during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to False
>
> required
>   Normally an error will be raised if a field is not supplied during deserialization. Set to false if this field is not required to be present during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to True.

So I have a model which has a field that's not nullable but I want it to be populated in the pre_save method, so I have set the field to `required=False` in serializer, but doesn't seem to work. I am still getting error when saving the record.

```
class FavoriteListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.FavoriteList
```

Update:
I have added `serializer_class = serializers.FavoriteListSerializer` to the ViewSet, now instead of getting `This field is required`, which I think got past the validation but then I am getting `This field cannot be null.` I have checked the pre_save method is not being executed, any ideas?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yeah, I ran into this issue at some point as well.  You need to also update the validation exclusions.

```
class FavoriteListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.FavoriteList

    def get_validation_exclusions(self):
        exclusions = super(FavoriteListSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + ['owner']
```

Comment: Hmmm I see, based on your answer, I tried adding validators=[] to serializer fields and still doesn't work. This kind of things are not working as advertised...

Comment: Did you add the `get_validation_exclusions()` method?  It overrides the existing validations on the model.

Comment: Yes after adding that method works. I was trying to add validators=[] to avoid overwriting get_validation_exclusions() but it didn't work

Comment: If you read through the source, `ModelSerializer`'s implementation grabs all listed serializer fields that are listed in the serializer, but adds back any model fields that aren't read-only or another ModelSerializer.  So, you have to help it out by removing the fields your view code is going to contribute.

Comment: Thanks, I still think this is a defect/imperfection as per documentation.

Comment: Tend to agree, you should leave an issue on the project https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues?state=open

Comment: I have raised an issue with the author and it's accepted. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1257

Comment: In 2020 it seems we do not need this anymore, however, it turned out that if owner is used with `unique_together` it has to be required. As a workaround, set the default=None in the serializer field constructor: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4456

Comment: Is everything in django just wanky and broken, every time I do something intuitive django is there to show me NOPE, you need to do some convoluted googling and changing before you do what you are obviously trying to d.

Comment: You can find better solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621808/7681229

Answer (score 41):

Late Entry to this thread. This issue was fixed in [django-rest-framework 2.3.13](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/tree/2.3.13). Here is the link of the [PR](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1405).

You use it like this in your case:

```
    class Meta:
        model = models.FavoriteList
        optional_fields = ['owner', ]
```

Comment: I've edited this to add a sample just in case. You should be "up" 40x to be on top because the answer with `get_validation_exclusions()` is not valid anymore (it was never called and PyCharm said there's no other declaration but mine to be found, so it's not the right solution).

Comment: I guess you meant 10x. 40x would be 160 which is 4 times 40. I can't do anything to reach there . Thanks for adding the sample, BTW.

Comment: This does not seem to exist anymore in the current version.

Answer (score 39):

In case somebody lands here with a similar issue, pay attention to the following attributes along with `required`:

[allow_blank](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield):

> If set to `True` then the empty string should be considered a valid value.

[allow_null](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null):

> Normally an error will be raised if `None` is passed to a serializer field.

[required](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required):

> Normally an error will be raised if a field is not supplied during deserialization.

I was straggling to figure out why I was getting a validation error with `required=False` where I had missed the `allow_null` attribute.

Comment: Check also if the database has columns with NOT NULL option.

Answer (score 23):

In 2020, for **DRF 3.12.x**, the approach that I prefer the approach that relies on
[Serializer's extra_kwargs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments).

So assuming your

```
class FavoriteListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.FavoriteList
        fields = ["owner"]  # and whatever other fields you want to expose
        extra_kwargs = {"owner": {"required": False, "allow_null": True}}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have unique_together constraint on one of the fields you are trying to set `required=False` you need to set `validators=[]` in serializers Meta like

```
class FavoriteListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = models.FavoriteList
        validators = []
```

Here is the original [answer](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2719#issuecomment-524562720)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    ...
```

As referred here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#advanced-field-defaults
There you can also find the case when you also wanna let the view show `owner`

Answer (score 0):

I would set model field to allow null value (and possible also default to None)

```
class FavoriteList(models.Model):
    owner = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=None)
```

Then it's possible to just leave owner field to Meta section. These fields, without any extra settings, will automatically get all attributes from model field and be non-required.

```
class FavoriteListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FavoriteList
        fields = ('owner',)
```