# Django REST Framework, pre_save() and serializer.is_valid(), how do they work?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I need to attach a user to a request, this seems like a fairly common thing to need to do, but it's turning out to be damn near impossible.

The docs for the Django REST Framework suggest using the pre_save method of the serializer class, which I did, but it doesn't get called when serializer.is_valid() is called, which makes it kind of worthless since without the user field the serializer fails validation.

I've seen a few suggestions but they seem like crazy hacks and/or don't work. Plus, I feel like this is way too common of a task to really need all the stuff I see people suggesting. I can't be the only person to need to attach a user to a object created in a REST request.

Comment: FYI an [issue has been raised on GitHub](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/821) regarding this but I don't think a solution has been finalised yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that I was using ListAPIView as the base class for my view class and it doesn't have the pre_save method defined. When I added some of the mixins which had it defined everything started working.

Seems weird that something used in a lot of the basic tutorials doesn't support such a basic feature, but live and learn.

Comment: how did you manage to add the call to `pre_save` in the serializer?

Comment: I didn't, turns out that pre_save is defined in the view mixins, so I handled this in the view, not the serializer. Though I doubt the ListAPIView uses pre_save, since it's read only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have access to the serialized data in the view pre_save method? Or are we supposed to use the raw REQUEST data?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried to mess with the serialized data in pre_save at all.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using one of the Authentication mechanisms described here (or Django Auth):

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html, you have a

`request.user` object.

When you create the serializer, pull it out of the request/pass it in when you instantiate.

```
MySerializer(data={"user": request.user, "otherField"=... })
```

If you are doing:

```
MySerializer(data=request.DATA)
```

You'll need to copy the `request.DATA` object:

```
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict
...
data = MultiValueDict(request.DATA)
data['user'] = request.user
MySerializer(data=data)
```

Answer (score 4):

`pre_save` is called after `is_valid` but before the instance is saved to the database.  You need to override the validation (using `def get_validation_exclusions(self):` on that user serializer field since you'll fix the validation issue in `pre_save`.  See my previous answer here:

[Django REST Framework serializer field required=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780731/django-cms-framework-serializer-field-required-false/19784306?noredirect=1#comment29428379_19784306)

I raised it up to the authors of DRF and they're going to investigating a more workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this problem is to mark required fields that are populated in `pre_save` as `read_only_fields` in the serializer.

To do that, add the following to the serializer class:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
        read_only_fields = ['user', 'my_other_field', ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new versions of DRF (3.x), pre_save was replaced by
`perform_create` and `perform_update`:
[Reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview)