# Trying to use the pre_save method to populate required fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two required fields on my model that I would like to populate in the pre_save method of my ModelViewSet. Despite setting them there, when submitting a .create() request I still get an error that the two fields are required and thus my object cannot be created.

I did some research on this and it seems that it's related to the is_valid() check being performed before pre_save is called... the recommended solution per some stack overflow articles that I've found:

[Django REST Framework, pre_save() and serializer.is_valid(), how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993951/django-rest-framework-pre-save-and-serializer-is-valid-how-do-they-work)

[Django REST Framework serializer field required=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780731/django-rest-framework-serializer-field-required-false/19784306#19784306)

Seems to be to override the get_validation_exclusions method. However that still doesn't seem to be working for me... I'm thinking at this point it might have to do with my model inheritance? Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated! This is what I'm working with -

serializers.py

```
class DaytimeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Daytime

    def get_validation_exclusions(self):
        exclusions = super(DaytimeSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + [ 'creation_datetime', 'creator_userprofile' ]
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name = 'friends')
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' UserProfile'


class Activity(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    creation_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    creator_userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    field3 = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    field4 = models.BooleanField()
    field5 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field1 + ' | ' + self.creator_userprofile.user.username

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Daytime(Activity):
    field6 = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='abc')
    field7 = models.BooleanField()
```

myviewsfile.py

```
class DaytimeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Daytime.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DaytimeSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.creator_userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username = self.request.user)
        obj.creation_datetime = timezone.now()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I 'fixed' this from the perspective that it now does what I was hoping it would but I'm not entirely sure that it's the best approach.

Adding these two lines to the DaytimeSerializer was the change:

```
class DaytimeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    creator_userprofile = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(source='creator_userprofile',view_name="userprofile-detail")
    creation_datetime = serializers.Field(source='creation_datetime')
```

Why would I need to explicitly tell the serializer that the creation_datetime field should come from the incoming JSONs creation_datetime? It's implicit for all the other fields... am I missing something here?

Also, now that I did this I no longer need to override the get_validation_exclusions method. I removed that bit.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the fields are required unless you declare them 'read only'.

You can add the fields that you don't need users to input to the [read_only_fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-which-fields-should-be-read-only).

Or, you can declare them manually as you did.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For answers posted on this site, it is preferred that they do not rely on content on external sites. That is, while it's OK to post links, it is also expected that the answer can be useful on itself even if the external site is down, gone, or changed. Do you think you could edit your answer to include the relevant part of the documentation you linked to?