# Django Rest Framework ModelSerialzer field doesn't respect required=False

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using django rest framework 3.1.1, I have the following serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(ContentSerializer):

    created_by = UserSerializer(required=False)
    content = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Content.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```

While the `content` field respects the `required=False` parameter, but `created_by` does not, which in result, gives me a list of "This field is required" validation errors inside the UserSerializer:

```
{"created_by":{"username":["This field is required."],"user_permissions":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."],"groups":["This field is required."],"profile_picture":["This field is required."]}}
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) section "Dealing with nested objects" it demonstrates the usage with a serializer.

**What I have tried:**

- My previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780731/django-rest-framework-serializer-field-required-false) about this and tried adding `get_validation_exclusions` did not help as I believe it's already been attended in this [issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1257).
- Changing created_by to `created_by = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False)` worked, but that is not what I want.
- A quick search in the existing issue shows I am not the only one having this problem:
  https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2719

**UPDATE:**

I have created a couple of test cases (see [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2719#issuecomment-103255656)) but couldn't replicate the issue, looks like it is only happening via Ajax Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `read_only=True` to the created_by field, now it's working fine.

```
class CommentSerializer(ContentSerializer):

    created_by = UserSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)
    content = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Content.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```