# Django REST replace empty to default

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST API set up and it works properly for valid incoming requests. In some of the requests, some of the fields are empty. Is there a way to provide default replacement values for those empty fields in the serializer, so that they would pass the validation test? For example, I have the following serializer:

```
class SearchRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  myfield1 = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, coerce_to_string=False, default=0, required=False, allow_null=True)
  class Meta:
    model = SearchRequest
    fields = ('myfield0', 'myfield1')
```

myfield1 is sometimes not provided. As shown above, I tried to default it to 0, but still getting

```
"myfield1":["A valid number is required."]
```

I don't know if it has any impact, but my requests are arrays and I'm using the serializer with the option many=True.

An example incomplete request would look like:

```
[{"myfield0":3, "myfield1":""}, {"myfield0":4, "myfield1":5}]
```

Comment: please check if this is helpful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780731/django-rest-framework-serializer-field-required-false

Comment: @Trying2Learn: thanks, I saw this but could not get the solution working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this error because `0` is not decimal.
Try `default=0.0` or `default=None`

**Update**

> An example incomplete request would look like:
>
> ```
> [{"myfield0":3, "myfield1":""}, {"myfield0":4, "myfield1":5}]
> ```

Problem here is that you are supplying `myfield1` as empty strings `"myfield1": ""`. Your request should look like this.

```
[{"myfield0":3}, {"myfield0":4, "myfield1":5}]
```

If there is no value for `myfield1` just don't put it in request. Otherwise you have to supply data which at least matches type. Because when field is not empty DRF does validation on it, `default` is used only when there is no value for field in submitted request.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#default

Comment: @Botond Than it is probably related to your request. Can you add request example which gives you this error?