# Rest Framework Serializer Field Read-Only not working

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a problem where a read-only attribute is not behaving as expected. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780731/django-rest-framework-serializer-field-required-false) and other sources to try and solve the issue but to no avail.

The endpoint is for saving and listing user favorites. Users can favourite multiple object types so I use the content types framework.

```
# serializers.py
class FavouriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    type = serializers.CharField(source='content_type', read_only=True)
    object = FavouriteObjectRelatedField(read_only=True)
    content_type = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    object_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        content_object = Favourites.objects.get_content_object(validated_data.get('object_id'),
                                                               validated_data.get('content_type'))
        user = kwargs.get('user')
        return Favourites.objects.create_favourite(content_object, user)

    class Meta:
        model = Favourites
        fields = ('type', 'object','user','content_type','object_id')
```

This is the `FavouriteObjectRelatedField` serializer that is required to dynamically serialize an object based on its type.

```
# serializers.py
class FavouriteObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    """
    A custom serializer to use for favourited objects.
    """
    def to_representation(self, value):
        """
        Serialize favourited objects using their respective serializer
        """
        if isinstance(value, Track):
            track = TrackBuilder(value).get_info()
            serializer = TrackSerializer(track, context=self.context, read_only=True)

        elif isinstance(value, News):
            serializer = NewsSerializer(value, context=self.context, read_only=True)

        else:
            raise Exception("Unexpected type of favourited object")

        return serializer.data
```

And the view. I override the `perform_create` method so to add the user instance which is retrieved from a url parameter.

```
#views.py
class UserFavouritesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
    serializer_class = FavouriteSerializer

    def get_user(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs.get('user_id')
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.get_user())

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Favourites.objects.user_favourites(self.get_user())
```

I always get a *user field required* error. However, if I removed the `user` field this error is obviously gone. Interestingly, if I rename the `user` field to `owner` I still get the same error with the field name specified as `user`. Error here:

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

### Update 1

As with one of the answers, I have already tried setting `required=True` but it has no effect.

Removing `read_only=True` is not an option since the user instance shouldn't be editable from this endpoint.

### Update 2

Another interesting development: if I remove the `type` field it works as expected. Strange but somehow accessing the `content_type` field must have an effect on validation.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `required=False` in there, instead of `read_only=True`.

```
user = UserSerializer(required=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, should have said. I already tried this and it has no effect. Also removing `read_only` is not an option since I don't want the User instance to be edited

Comment: @JacobWindsor You still getting `user field is required` with this? Can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: yes, i get the exact same error. Might be a stupid question but is there a simple way to get the stacktrace in DRF?

Comment: I had a problem where a StringRelatedField was being required. Adding both read_only=True and required=False got me running again, though I don't quite see why both would be needed.