# ModelSerializer doesn't respect the required attribute on a field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

If I have:

```
class Example(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time = DateTimeRangeField(required=False)
```

it will fail with an error:

```
{'time': ['This field is required.']}
```

However if this was serializers.Serializer it respects the required attribute on the field.  Has anybody else come across this?
Any ideas on how to make a field not required?

Comment: I think you need to set `blank = True` for time field in model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780731/django-rest-framework-serializer-field-required-false read answer 1 and 2.

Comment: show your model, serializers are just like a forms, it just validates request data, you must pass `blank=True` and `null=True` for time field in the model

Comment: @Satendra, I have tried that and it gives same message

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeRangeField` is *not* a Django REST framework field so it's like you did not provide any field at all.