# Getting validation error field can not be null, even if null=True in model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've a foreign key in my model and this field can be null.

```
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="status")
```

When i send a request with this field as null i get validation error saying

```
[
    {
        "status": [
            "This field may not be null."
        ]
    }
]
```

Even though I have set null=True I'm not sure why it's throwing me that validation error? Can anyone please help me with this.

**Update 1:**

This is the below sample serializers I'm using

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)
    status = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = model_name
        list_serializer_class = SampleListSerializerClass
        fields = ("status", ...few other model fields)
```

Comment: `null=True` just says the database column can have a value of `NULL`. `blank=True` is what allows the field to be blank. Can you show us your form please?

Comment: And just to double check, you have run `migrate`?

Comment: I'm using Django rest framework. This is throwing me when my body of the request is not valid. so in the request, if I send status: null it throws me a validation error.

Comment: Yes, I've migrated it. But still getting the error.

Comment: @AashayAmballi where is your form ?

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede I'm using Django Rest Framework. It's throwing me when serializer is not valid. So basically when I send request from postman with the status values as null. It throws me the validation error. Even though I've set null=True in my models.py status field. :(

Comment: Ah yes, what about your serializer then?

Comment: @KentShikama What do you need to see in the serializers?

Comment: Your fields. For example, `required`, `allow_null`, or `allow_blank`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172099/2750819

Comment: I figured it out, I forgot to add allow_null=True in the serializer field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202543/discussion-between-aashay-amballi-and-kent-shikama).